# Call a function in Python file using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have python file called testing_file.py:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import MySQLdb

    # Open database connection
    class DB():
        def __init__(self, server, user, password, db_name):
            db = MySQLdb.connect(server, user, password, db_name )
            self.cur = db.cursor()

        def time_statistic(self, start_date, end_date):

            time_list = {}

            sql = "SELECT activity_log.datetime, activity_log.user_id FROM activity_log"
            self.cur.execute(sql)
            self.date_data = self.cur.fetchall()
            for content in self.date_data:

                timestamp = str(content[0])
                datetime_object = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                timestamps = datetime.strftime(datetime_object, "%Y-%m-%d")

                if start_dt <= timestamps and timestamps <= end_dt:
                    if timestamps not in time_list:
                        time_list[timestamps]=1
                    else:
                        time_list[timestamps]+=1

                    return json.dumps(time_list)

    start_date = datetime.strptime(str('2017-4-7'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    start_dt = datetime.strftime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    end_date = datetime.strptime(str('2017-5-4'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_dt = datetime.strftime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")        

    db = DB("host","user_db","pass_db","db_name")
    db.time_statistic(start_date, end_date)
```

I want to access the result `(time_list)` thru API using Flask. This is what i've wrote so far, doesn't work and also I've tried another way:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from testing_api import *

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def get():
        db = DB("host","user_db","pass_db","db_name")
        d = db.time_statistic()
        return d

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Question: This is my first time work with API and Flask. Can anyone please help me thru this. Any hints are appreciated. Thank you

I've got empty list as result {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with what you are doing.

1.> `def get(self, DB)` why `self`? This function does not belong to a class. It is not an instance function. self is a reference of the class instance when an instance method is called. Here not only it is not needed, it is plain and simple wrong.

2.> If you look into flask's routing declaration a little bit, you will see how you should declare a route with parameter. This is the [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules). In essence you should something like this

```
@app.route("/path/<variable>")
def route_func(variable):
    return variable
```

3.> Finally, one more thing I would like to mention, Please do not call a regular python file `test_<filename>.py` unless you plan to use it as a unit testing file. This is very confusing.

Oh, and you have imported DB from your module already no need to pass it as a parameter to a function. It should be anyway available inside it.

Comment: "This method does not belong to a class" => actually it's a function, not a method. "self is a reference of the class to which a method belongs to" => nope, it's a reference to the instance on which the method has been called.

Comment: yes, thank you for your comment. I didn't check it clearly. But I've made some changes in my question, but get empty list as result. Could you please help me to see what is wrong with that? Thank you

Comment: I got it!! Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that are wrong (ranging from "useless and unclear" to "plain wrong") in your code.

wrt/ the `TypeError`: as the error message says, your `get()` function expects two arguments (`self` and `DB`) which won't be passed by Flask - and are actually not used in the function anyway. Remove both arguments and you'll get rid of this error - just to find out you now have a `NameError` on the first line of the `get()` function (obviously since you didn't import `time_statistic` nor defined `start_date` and `end_date`).

Comment: That's true. Now I've made some changes, no error but give me empty list. Maybe I miss some part again. Anyway thank for your comment

Comment: I got it!! Thanks for your guidance